# Parsing human-language dates into a Date object

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

What would be the most foolproof method of converting dates (that is for a project I am working on that uses a ML text extractor) that humans enter into a Date() object.

This seems like quite a simple issue, but I can't find a foolproof solution. This is because the formats vary so widely between people entering dates like "Feburary 20, 2021" to "1/1/20", as well as ones that use different formats like "2021/1/3".

Is there a prebuilt package that someone knows about?

EDIT: After some digging and experimenting, the only solution I found was to use moment.js (thanks to cWerning for the suggestion, as well as others who suggested other ideas) and input multiple templates like this:

```
moment(**date**,["YYYY/MM/DD","DD/MM/YYYY",etc... with other formats]
```

EDIT: Another solution that worked for my purposes is a GitHub project called [Chrono](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono) that does natural language processing, which is what I was initially looking for.

Comment: When dealing with dates do yourself a favor and work with https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: also, if humans are entering it.. you can CONTROL the format in which they enter it(instead of having one blank input form, have several select tags with options of month, day and year) then you make the data out of that standardized thing

Comment: If you're trying to extract dates from arbitrary text, I think this is basically impossible unless your ML is  clever enough to  (among other things) determine whether the human who entered the text is American (mm/dd/yy) or European (dd/mm/yy).

Comment: @cWerning Thank you for the suggestion. I found out that moment.js offers the ability to add multiple custom "templates" for recognizing date formats. (Goes through them until it finds a valid date)
-TheBombSquad (Can't Mention Multiple) Thank you as well for the suggestion. It sounds useful for other situations but in my case, I can't control how it goes in.  

-DanielBeck Yea. While the solution that I found with the help of cWerning works, it is sort of unviable so perhaps maybe a more advanced ML model in the future might help. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can control **HOW** humans enter the data to ensure it is understood by a program. Example below :D

```js
let values=id=>document.getElementById(id).value //to get each wanted value with relative ease >:D
let elems=id=>document.getElementById(id) //to get each wanted elem with relative ease >:D
let twoDigit=num=>{if(num>9){return(num)}return(0+''+num)} //this will help in Date.parse formatting >:D
elems("btn").addEventListener('click',onClick) //scroll to see the onClick function >:D


//for placing days
for(let i=1;i<=31;i++){elems("day").innerHTML+=`<option value="${twoDigit(i)}">${i}</option>`}

//for placing months
var monthsArr=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
for(let i=0;i<monthsArr.length;i++){
  elems("month").innerHTML+=`<option value="${twoDigit(i+1)}">${monthsArr[i]}</option>`
}

//for placing years
let maxYear=2050, minYear=1950 //can set these to whatever
for(let i=minYear;i<=maxYear;i++){elems("year").innerHTML+=`<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`}

//function that runs when you click "Submit Date"
function onClick(ev){
  let date=new Date(Date.parse(`${values("year")}-${values("month")}-${values("day")}T00:00:00.000`))
  if(date){return alert(`New Date Recorded:\n${date}`)} //inside here you can also store correct dates or whatever(inside this if statement)
  alert("INVALID DATE.. hint, February 31st is NOT A REAL DATE")
}
```

```html
<h2>Please Choose a Date :D</h2>
<h3>Do note that INVALID dates would be rejected :0</h3>
<select id="day"></select>
<select id="month"></select>
<select id="year"></select>
<button id="btn">Submit Date</button>
```